# Android: multiple intents to gmail

Tags: android, android-intent

I have one link to gmail.When I click to the link the intent open two or more windows with gmail. I think maybe this is the main problem "Intent.ACTION_SEND".

Thanks in advance.

```
// TextView button for Email address
emailLink.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        //email address
        String emailAddress = "some_email@gmail.com";
        String subject = "Write a topic";

        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[]{emailAddress});
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, subject);
        intent.setType("text/plain");
        startActivity(intent);

        return true;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you add logs to see if your `onTouch` is called multiple times ?

Try to replace `setOnTouchListener` by `setOnClickListener`.
I think that `setOnTouchListener` is called for `ACTION_DOWN` + `ACTION_UP` (when you click and when your remove your finger from the `TextView`)

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
 intent.setType("text/plain");
```

with

```
 // need this to prompts email client only
 intent.setType("message/rfc822");
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer,but I still have multiple intents when I click to the link.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
Intent intent= new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);  
                    intent.setType("application/octet-stream");
```

Comment: try to debug it using breakdown. I hope your intent is firing more then once.